# How to check how many times a specific day occurs between two dates?

Tags: swift, date, calendar

I am trying to calculate how many times a specific day occurs between two dates i.e a start date and an end date in Swift. I'll try to explain with an example.

I have 3 values with me. They are startDate, endDate and a specificDate (particular day in a month).

Let's say:

```
specificDate = 8    // specific day in a month
startDate = 07-11-2019
endDate = 07-01-2020
```

From the above example I can say specifcDate 8 occurs 2 times in between the startDate and endDate, i.e on Nov 8th and Dec 8th.

How can I implement or achieve this specificDate occurrences calculation between two dates programmatically in Swift?

The above values are just for example. There can be any value for those fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use the `Calendar nextDate(after:matching:matchingPolicy:)` method passing a `DateComponents` instance with the desired day set.

```
extension Calendar {
    func count(of day: Int, between startDate: Date, and endDate: Date) -> Int {
        let matchComps = DateComponents(day: day)
        var dates = [Date]()
        var date = startDate
        while let matchingDate = self.nextDate(after: date, matching: matchComps, matchingPolicy: .nextTime), matchingDate <= endDate {
            dates.append(matchingDate)
            date = matchingDate
        }

        print("Found \(dates) between \(startDate) and \(endDate)")

        return dates.count
    }
}

let startDate = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2019, month: 7, day: 11))!
let endDate = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2020, month: 7, day: 1))!
let count = Calendar.current.count(of: 8, between: startDate, and: endDate)
```

Output:

> Found [2019-08-08 06:00:00 +0000, 2019-09-08 06:00:00 +0000, 2019-10-08 06:00:00 +0000, 2019-11-08 07:00:00 +0000, 2019-12-08 07:00:00 +0000, 2020-01-08 07:00:00 +0000, 2020-02-08 07:00:00 +0000, 2020-03-08 07:00:00 +0000, 2020-04-08 06:00:00 +0000, 2020-05-08 06:00:00 +0000, 2020-06-08 06:00:00 +0000] between 2019-07-11 06:00:00 +0000 and 2020-07-01 06:00:00 +0000

Of course the exact output will depend on your timezone.